# Testing a file that calls its own function

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I have a file that is the entry-point to my application;

```
const main = async () => {
   // Do stuff
}

main().then();
```

I understand that I can export the `main` function, delete the call in the first file and in a separate file import and call the function there;

```
const entry = require('./rewritten-entry.js');
entry.main().then();
```

But for arguments sake lets say I really want to test this first file's `main` function. As soon as I import the file in my test, the main function will execute before I even reach the test code;

```
const entry = require('./original-entry.js')    // <-- main function executes here

const test = {
  // Do test stuff
}
```

For a test, I don't want this to happen. Likewise I don't want to mock the function since it is exactly what I want to test.

I see this common 'init' logic all over the place so I imagine there is a way to test this.

Comment: If you understand that you can restructure it for testing, why not _do that_? As your example shows, importing the file runs the function, all you can do at that point is assert on any side-effects.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - isn't it reasonable to want to test *exactly* the source that will be in production?

Comment: Yes? I'm not saying the source you test should be different to what's in prod, you'd be refactoring both (because it's the same code).